# CSS/HTML Align images in grid on wordpress page

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using a 2x2 grid on a wordpress page to display some images that change during a mouseover.

Using a 2 column 1 row grid, the images are perfectly horizontally aligned, but when I add a second row the bottom two images get out of alignment.

I put this code into my CSS stylesheet

```
.grid {
    width: 704px;
    margin: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.grid-m1 {
    float: left;
    width: 22px;
    height: 1px;
}
.grid-c1 {
    float: left;
    width: 320px;
}
.grid-m2 {
    float: left;
    width: 22px;
    height: 1px;
}
.grid-c2 {
    float: left;
    width: 320px;
}
```

Then in my new page I put in:

```
<div class="grid">
    <p class="grid-m1"></p>
    <p class="grid-c1"><a id="top left" href="top left">
<img title="Top Left" onmouseover="this.src='http://quickfoqus.com/studies/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Top-Left-solid.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://quickfoqus.com/studies/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Top-Left.png'" alt="" src="http://quickfoqus.com/studies/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Top-Left.png" />
</a>
    </p>
    <p class="grid-m2"></p>
    <p class="grid-c2"><a id="top right" href="top right">
<img title="Top Right" onmouseover="this.src='http://quickfoqus.com/studies/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Top-Right-solid.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://quickfoqus.com/studies/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Top-Right.png'" alt="" src="http://quickfoqus.com/studies/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Top-Right.png" />
</a>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="grid">
    <p class="grid-m1"></p>
    <p class="grid-c1"><a id="bottom left" href="bottom left">
<img title="Bottom Left" onmouseover="this.src='http://quickfoqus.com/studies/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Bottom-Right-solid.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://quickfoqus.com/studies/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Bottom-Right.png'" alt="" src="http://quickfoqus.com/studies/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Bottom-Right.png" />
</a>
    </p>
    <p class="grid-m2"></p>
    <p class="grid-c2">
        <img src="http://quickfoqus.com/studies/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/focus-group.png" />
    </p>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/DZqQJ/

As you can see by looking at my site: quickfoqus.com/studies/test I cannot get these 4 images to line up properly on the grid.

I tried vertical-align tags on my css but this did not seem to work.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just as a comment, your HTML is invalid. You have `id`s with spaces in it. And also `href` with spaces.

Comment: thank you, made necessary changes

Answer (score 1):

Your plain gradient images have empty space at the top and side(s). Your people image does not. Here's the  layout with margins applied to that image to get things lined up:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/DZqQJ/1/

```
<img src="http://.../focus-group.png" style="margin: 10px 0 0 15px;" />
```

Comment: ok, I tried the adding the new style to this image and was able to get the pictures vertically aligned. I couldn't, however, get them to horizontally align. I am just going to crop the images in photoshop to make them all even. Thank you!

Comment: That's what I was suggesting you do. They're horizontally aligned in my demo, for what that's worth.